# How to convert this list into dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
paths = [['test_data', 'new_directory', 'ok.txt'], ['test_data', 'reads_1.fq'], ['test_data', 'test_ref.fa']]
```

I want to convert this into dictionary like this:

```
{'test_data': ['ok.txt', 'reads_1.fq'], 'test_data/new_directory', ['ok.txt']}
```

The list is dynamic. The purpose of this is to create a simple tree structure. I want to do this using itertools like this:

```
from itertools import izip
i = iter(a)
b = dict(izip(i, i))
```

Is something like this possible? Thanks

Comment: I think test_data must be : `'test_data': ['reads_1.fq', 'test_ref.fa']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> lis = [['test_data', 'new_directory', 'ok.txt'], ['test_data', 'reads_1.fq'], 
for item in lis:                                                                                           
    key = "/".join(item[:-1])
    dic[key].append(item[-1])
...     
>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'list'>,
{'test_data': ['reads_1.fq', 'test_ref.fa'],
 'test_data/new_directory': ['ok.txt']})
```

using simple `dict`:

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> for item in lis:
    key = "/".join(item[:-1])
    dic.setdefault(key, []).append(item[-1])
...     
>>> dic
{'test_data': ['reads_1.fq', 'test_ref.fa'],
 'test_data/new_directory': ['ok.txt']}
```

Comment: +1 I did the same thing but I thought my output was wrong (seems like OP was wrong)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks mate!! I will accept the answer when I can.

Answer (score 15):

can try this also,

```
list1=['a','b','c','d']
list2=[1,2,3,4]
```

we want to zip these two lists and create a dictionary dict_list

```
dict_list = zip(list1, list2)
dict(dict_list)
```

this will give:

```
dict_list = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4 }
```