# How to convert List in to Dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this :

```
list1 = ["a:b","x:y","s:e","w:x"]
```

I want convert into dictionary like this:

```
dict = {'a':'b', 'x':'y','s':'e','w':'x'}
```

The list is dynamic. How could i achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert this list into dictionary in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144889/how-to-convert-this-list-into-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
>>> list1 = ["a:b","x:y","s:e","w:x"]
>>> dict(elem.split(':') for elem in list1)
{'a': 'b', 'x': 'y', 's': 'e', 'w': 'x'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
super_dict = dict()
for el in list1:
  super_dict[el[0]] = el[-1]
```

Of course there could be problems if the keys are identical, you'll need to add code if needed